# How do I create a remote git repository on my github account with python or push a local git repo to my github account using python?

Tags: python, git, github, github-api, pygithub

I'm new to python. What I'm trying to do is to create a remote git repository on my GitHub account and then be able to clone it locally. I want to do all this in a python program. If it is easier to create a local git repo and then push it to my GitHub account then that is fine as well. All I can do right now is create a local git repo and that took only 2 lines of code.

```py
import git
import os
repo_dir = os.path.join("testrepo")
r = git.Repo.init(repo_dir)
```

what I need to be able to do now is push this local repo into my GitHub account to have a remote one as well. As I said if doing the other way around is better/easier then that works as well. I read a lot about the different APIs that are provided (Pygithub, Github) but the documentation is giving me a headache. I have a hard time understanding what the methods return and how to use them. The goal is to be able to automate the process of creating a project and pushing it to GitHub with a python script that I will then run from the command line. Also, this is the first time I'm posting on StackOverflow so I apologize if I did not follow any conventions. Again I would appreciate clear explanations since it has only been 3 days since I started with python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-api%5D+%5Bpython%5D+create+repository

Comment: check this https://github.com/benhoyt/pygit/blob/master/pygit.py

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a remote repository, and then cloning it to your local machine.

Then to create the remote repository, you're going to have to make an API request to the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/), but first, you'll need an access token from GitHub.  You can make one of these from their web UI.

And then we'll use [Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) to make the POST request to the GitHub API:

```
import subprocess
import requests
import sys

# Notice that you username and token are required here
r = requests.post(
  "https://api.github.com/users/<username>/repos?access_token=<generated token>", 
  data={
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "description": "This is your first repository",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "private": false,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_projects": true,
  "has_wiki": true
})

if r.status_code != 200:
  sys.exit()
```

And now that the remote repository has been created, you can clone it to your machine

```
clone_url = r.text.clone_url
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'clone', clone_url], cwd=repo_dir)
```

I didn't actually run this code, but I think it should get you pretty close, good luck!